# sub query in apache pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Looking for some help on writing sub query in apache pig. For example I have the below two relations -

```
A
sam 12 grad maths
sony 13 postgrad english

B
maths {(4.5,sam),(4,david)}
english {(4.2,peter),(3.9,rob)}
```

Join the two relations by subject i.e. A by A.$3 and B by B.$0 and have to write query which will give  the output as -

```
sam 12 grad maths 4.5
sony 13 postgrad english
```

Basically it should check for the matching subject in B and then look for name in it.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would approach this is to [flatten](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/basic.html#flatten) the `B` relation, then do a left outer join onto A.

First, to flatten the relation out:

```
C = FOREACH B GENERATE $0, FLATTEN($1);
```

This translates your date into:

```
maths, 4.5, sam
maths, 4, david
english, 4.2, peter
english, 3.9, rob
```

Now, you can just do a [JOIN](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/basic.html#join-inner) to bring the data together (I'm renaming this stuff to keep my head straight):

```
J = JOIN A BY (Aname, Asubject), C BY (Bname, Bsubject);
J2 = FOREACH J GENERATE Astudent, Agrade, Alevel, Asubject, Bscore;
```

`dump J2` will output only `sam, 12, grad, maths, 4.5`.

But, there is a problem. It looks like you want to have a `NULL` value if your item in list A does not show up in list B. This is a job for a [`LEFT OUTER` join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join), and luckily, [Pig can do outer joins](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/basic.html#join-outer). Modify the above code as follows:

```
J = JOIN A BY (Aname, Asubject) LEFT OUTER, C BY (Bname, Bsubject);
J2 = FOREACH J GENERATE Astudent, Agrade, Alevel, Asubject, Bscore;
```

`dump J2` here will output, which is what I think you want:

```
sam, 12, grad, maths, 4.5
sony, 13, postgrad, english,
```